# Yii2 model attribute without corresponding field in database

Tags: yii2

To make a long story short I am building some simple audit functionality that stores a database records' previous values in an auditing table.  I use "getOldAttributes" to find the old values of all database columns for the record being audited.  For one model, I have another attribute named permissions (does not exist as database column), that I would like to store right along side the other oldAttributes.  Adding "public $permissions;" to the top of my ActiveRecord class is working for passing data from the form into the model for processing but that attribute is not included in the getOldAttributs call.  I have read various ideas on using getters/setters to make that attribute work like a regular AR attribute but nothing is working or even really making sense.

TLDR; AR class has public attribute that I want to be able to access like all other database attributes (but without actually saving in the database).

Answer (score 1):

Try to override getAttributes() method of ActiveRecord:

```
public function getAttributes($names = null, $except = [])
{
    return array_merge(['permissions'], parent::getAttributes($names, $except));
}
```

Comment: Rather than getAttributes() I overrode attributes() so now my class opens with the following: public $permissions; public function attributes() { return array_merge(['permissions'], parent::attributes()); }
Then later I forcibly set the old value with "$this->setOldAttribute('permissions', 'oldValue'));"  This all works (so thank you) but it seems like there should be an easier way especially since the attributes() doc seems to indicate simply declaring $permissions as public should be enough to make it "just work."

Comment: Just as a note, I had to use ['permissions' = null] rather than just ['permissions'] which seemed to create a value of permissions rather than a key.